# Installing dropbox using pip hangs

Tags: python, pip, dropbox-api, urllib3

I want to install dropbox using '**pip install dropbox**'
but it constantly hangs when it comes to collect urllib3.
Any idea?

```
(venv) E:\Python\DropBoxClient\webapp>pip install dropbox
Collecting dropbox
  Using cached dropbox-8.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.16.2 (from dropbox)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.3.0 (from dropbox)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.16.2->dropbox)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.16.2->dropbox)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing urllib3 directly

Comment: Yes, '**pip install urllib3**' has the same effect. Also hangs!

Comment: Please add the output of `$ pip install urllib3 -vvv` to the question.

Comment: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Collecting urllib3
  1 location(s) to search for versions of urllib3:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/urllib3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4650
  Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/"

Comment: ...Caching b/c date exists and max-age > 0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and to get moving again I d/l'd url lib: https://pypi.python.org/simple/urllib3/

I needed the same version you did, so i picked 1.22 and unzipped it and:

```
(sonikachu) masterblaster@thunderdrome:~/pokemon/sonikachu$ pip install -e ~/Downloads/urllib3-1.22
```

I did the rest of my pip install -r requiremnets no problemos